# Decode South African (ZA) Drivers License

Tags: barcode

I am writing a solution to scan PDF417 barcode (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF417) at the back of a South African drivers license for iOS. I can't find any documentation or specification how to decode barcode. Does anyone have a link to a specification or sample code that can decode driver license data stored in PDF417 barcode? Thanks

Comment: googling "ios barcode 417" turns up several options.  http://code.google.com/p/zxing/ claims to support it.

Comment: anyone know what data we can get form the barcode?

Answer (score 24):

The data after scanning the PDF417 barcode is 720 bytes. First 4 bytes indicate the version of barcode.
Version 2 covers all currently valid licenses.

Version 1: `01 e1 02 45`

Version 2: `01 9b 09 45`

Next two bytes are zero (`00 00`).

Remaining 714 bytes form 6 blocks - 5 blocks of 128, 1 block of 74.

Different keys are used depending on version and and block size.

Version 1, 128 bytes

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGXAoGBAP7S4cJ+M2MxbncxenpSxUmBOVGGvkl0dgxyUY1j4FRKSNCIszLFsMNw
x2XWXZg8H53gpCsxDMwHrncL0rYdak3M6sdXaJvcv2CEePrzEvYIfMSWw3Ys9cRl
HK7No0mfrn7bfrQOPhjrMEFw6R7VsVaqzm9DLW7KbMNYUd6MZ49nAhEAu3l//ex/
nkLJ1vebE3BZ2w==
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Version 1, 74 bytes:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MGACSwD/POxrX0Djw2YUUbn8+u866wbcIynA5vTczJJ5cmcWzhW74F7tLFcRvPj1
tsj3J221xDv6owQNwBqxS5xNFvccDOXqlT8MdUxrFwIRANsFuoItmswz+rfY9Cf5
zmU=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Version 2, 128 bytes:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGWAoGBAMqfGO9sPz+kxaRh/qVKsZQGul7NdG1gonSS3KPXTjtcHTFfexA4MkGA
mwKeu9XeTRFgMMxX99WmyaFvNzuxSlCFI/foCkx0TZCFZjpKFHLXryxWrkG1Bl9+
+gKTvTJ4rWk1RvnxYhm3n/Rxo2NoJM/822Oo7YBZ5rmk8NuJU4HLAhAYcJLaZFTO
sYU+aRX4RmoF
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Version 2, 74 bytes:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MF8CSwC0BKDfEdHKz/GhoEjU1XP5U6YsWD10klknVhpteh4rFAQlJq9wtVBUc5Dq
bsdI0w/bga20kODDahmGtASy9fae9dobZj5ZUJEw5wIQMJz+2XGf4qXiDJu0R2U4
Kw==
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Decrypt each block separately. Decrypted with RSA ENCRYPT function using
the public key.

Comment: @SweetToe can you provide some code to use these keys ?

Comment: @Antoniossss yes this actually works, im not done yet after the decryption you still have to decode some information but basic information is visible

Comment: @DonaldJansen did you ever manage to get this working? I've been looking all over the Internet for a way to get readable info from the barcode. Any assistance would greatly be appreciated... even just a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: @pjdupreez just look in MyBroadBand there is enough code that will help you get started. I have succeeded using the above keys. I wanted to email you but your profile doesn't show your email address.
Anyway here is the link
https://mybroadband.co.za/vb/showthread.php/382187-Decode-Drivers-Licence-Barcode

Comment: The following is from D.O.T
The DLCA is looking into the option of providing an a public key for the current driving licence taking into consideration all the legal requirements. At the moment, we are able to provide the decryption key to you until we have completed our internal processes.  Please also note that we are also planning to redesign the whole encryption, we may also remove the encryption completely in future

Comment: @DonaldJansen. Thank you. WRT the DOT comment... I was concerned that they would change the encryption, but if they are going to remove it entirely that would be great! PS: I have no idea why my email is not showing or how to make it display for the public :/

Comment: I have encountered a new version with the header `01 87 06 45`. Does anybody have a key for this version?

Comment: Has anybody had any success with this in the last couple of months? Exctracting the data and image from the encoding?

Comment: @SweetToe, do you have the new keys for `01 87 06 45` by any chance?

Comment: @TheGwa do you have the HEX value, if you could send it we can look into it if you haven't found a solution yet

Comment: I know I am very late to the party, but I am struggling to see what to do once all the blocks are decrypted. I managed to decrypt all the block using RSA encrypt, but what do I do with all the seperate decrypted blocks now? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Once it is decrypted it is also encoded so you will need a bit of experience with HEX values

Comment: I've got it to work in Android and iOs on both versions, however some people found a 3rd version, I haven't come accross it yet, I am mostly struggling to scan the PDF417 using a phone camera. but 2D barcode scanners is working

Comment: Seems like there are alot of people getting it to work. So no use in trying to keep the solution a secret anymore 

Answer (score 1):

Based on the RSA public key, the [incomplete document](https://github.com/ugommirikwe/sa-license-decoder/blob/master/SPEC.md), and the [C# open source project](https://github.com/DanieLeeuwner/Reply.Net.SADL/blob/master/Reply.Net.SADL/Reply.Net.SADL/DriversLicenceService.cs), I've successfully decoded the South African driving license in Python except for the image part.

[image]

Steps:

1. Load the RSA public key from the PEM format.

   ```py
   pubKey = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(pk128)
   ```
2. Decrypt the data decoded from PDF417:

   ```py
    all = bytearray()
    pubKey = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(pk128)
    start = 6
    for i in range(5):
        block = data[start: start + 128]
        input = int.from_bytes(block, byteorder='big', signed=False)
        output = pow(input, pubKey.e, mod=pubKey.n)

        decrypted_bytes = output.to_bytes(128, byteorder='big', signed=False)
        all += decrypted_bytes

        start = start + 128

    pubKey = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(pk74)
    block = data[start: start + 74]
    input = int.from_bytes(block, byteorder='big', signed=False)
    output = pow(input, pubKey.e, mod=pubKey.n)

    decrypted_bytes = output.to_bytes(74, byteorder='big', signed=False)
    all += decrypted_bytes
   ```
3. Parse the data:

   ```py
   def parse_data(data):

       index = 0
       for i in range(0, len(data)):
           if data[i] == 0x82:
               index = i
               break

       # Section 1: Strings
       vehicleCodes, index = readStrings(data, index + 2, 4)
       print(f'Vehicle codes: {vehicleCodes}')

       surname, index, delimiter = readString(data, index)
       print(f'Surname: {surname}')

       initials, index, delimiter = readString(data, index)
       print(f'Initials: {initials}')

       PrDPCode = ''
       if delimiter == 0xe0:
           PrDPCode, index, delimiter = readString(data, index)
           print(f'PrDP Code: {PrDPCode}')

       idCountryOfIssue, index, delimiter = readString(data, index)
       print(f'ID Country of Issue: {idCountryOfIssue}')

       licenseCountryOfIssue, index, delimiter = readString(data, index)
       print(f'License Country of Issue: {licenseCountryOfIssue}')

       vehicleRestrictions, index = readStrings(data, index, 4)
       print(f'Vehicle Restriction: {vehicleRestrictions}')

   ...
   ```

You can visit [https://github.com/yushulx/South-Africa-driving-license/blob/main/sadl/**init**.py](https://github.com/yushulx/South-Africa-driving-license/blob/main/sadl/__init__.py) to see the full code.

The Python package has been published to [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/south-africa-driving-license/). You can install it via `pip install south-africa-driving-license`.