# decode south african za-drivers-license

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa, public-key

In reference to this discussion: [Decode South African (ZA) Drivers License](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549231/decode-south-african-za-drivers-license)

Please assist I seem to be getting an error trying to create PublicKey instance in Java on android. I have pasted the error below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
Cipher asymmetricCipher = null;
asymmetricCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec128 = new X509EncodedKeySpec(key128block);
X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec74 = new X509EncodedKeySpec(key74block);

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
Key key = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec128);
asymmetricCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

byte[] plainText = asymmetricCipher.doFinal(topBlocksData[0]);
```

Comment: Looks like the key does not have the correct format. Did you maybe forget to remove a layer of Base64 encoding?

Comment: key128block = Base64.decode(
keys[2].replaceAll("-----(BEGIN|END) RSA PUBLIC KEY-----", "").replaceAll("\n", "").getBytes(),
Base64.DEFAULT
);

Comment: @anos did you get a successful scan working with this code?

Comment: I used a different approach. But check answer by @james-k-polk

Comment: @AnosK.Mhazo how much of the information did you get extracted? did you manage to get the image as well?

Comment: I got everything including image

Comment: @AnosK.Mhazo can you please share the details how to scan and get the south africa driver license details?

Comment: Unfortunately you cant unless you have public keys to decrypt the data. Do you @Google

Comment: @AnosK.Mhazo How can we get the public key? i don't have. When i am trying to scan the drive license with Encodin ASCII using chainway device but geting different type of log like below: �����4n)L�� ]�� � �
l,�Kf��T�g �?��/7�(�N���0 n�{j ���� �
S�8$�-����E0:��i"c� =G����$_:^
 9��f�A�~ � U-H�$�Iga� �<�
 ��b�r�~�2�J�$Pba�� ��)��i���� �HjNe��0�T�@�|���F B� Y���� �I�R����{� N�����}7@f���D\� 0
��9    ���!K���B���l`�����j� � '�7� ~� o����Oo�A�� ���� ���r�(�
$�`k �A�

Comment: I ended up looking for a paid solution - these keys are extremely rare to come across. Join ZATech slack and look for Z - he is the one I ended up working with. https://zatech.co.za/

Comment: https://scan.apextechnology.co.za/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoded public keys you're trying to read are not of the format expected by [`X509EncodedKeySpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html). Instead they are of an even simpler form which, unfortunately, is not supported by Java. However, you can use the Bouncycastle or Spongycastle library to code up a small java routine to parse the values. The code below is copied from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565772/decode-asn1-sequence-to-rsa-public-key-using-java#29571639) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565772/decode-asn1-sequence-to-rsa-public-key-using-java).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Integer;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERSequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DLSequence;

public class RsaAsn1Example {
// ...
    public static BigInteger [] parseASN1RsaPublicKey(byte [] encoded) throws IOException {
        ASN1InputStream asn1_is = new ASN1InputStream(encoded);
        DLSequence dlSeq = (DLSequence) asn1_is.readObject();
        ASN1Integer asn1_n = (ASN1Integer) dlSeq.getObjectAt(0);
        ASN1Integer asn1_e = (ASN1Integer) dlSeq.getObjectAt(1);
        asn1_is.close();
        return new BigInteger[]{ asn1_n.getPositiveValue(), asn1_e.getPositiveValue()};
    }
// ....
}
```

The values returned by `parseASN1RsaPublicKey` can be supplied to an [`RsaPublicKeySpec`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/spec/RSAPublicKeySpec.html) constructor to create the public key.

Also examine [divanov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565772/decode-asn1-sequence-to-rsa-public-key-using-java#29571795) to the same questions for an alternative.